# Google Analytics unexplained spike

Tags: google-analytics

My client's Google Analytics has had a spike everyday from May 6th (from 0 - 100.)  This is in a city that he is not optimized for and does very little business in.  The hits are coming in direct to the website.  My client is concerned that it has something to do with competition using his site as a price shopping device.  I can't view the ip to see where they are coming from and his site is not built in PHP so the work around doesn't work here.  Any thoughts?  Could it be a "referring site" situation and if so is there a way for me to find out what the referring site is?

Answer (score 1):

One day a client using opera browser put an autorefresh in my page, causing 1 visit/second for two days
I was worried seeing the google analytics, a , but on the server logs I saw that it was all from a single ip in a predefined amount of time - temporary IP ban and I was done :-P

You can never image what users will think

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to view your webserver's logs? It depends where your site is hosted but most providers should(?) allow you to download the raw logfiles.

You should be able to look at these around the time mentioned on Google Analytics to try and get an idea of what's causing the spike - and find out the IP, referrer and possibly User-agent (Browser) of any visitors at that time.